# Staging environment to manage the catalog

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, staging, catalog-staging

I would like to be able to manage the catalog in a staging environment and make sure that in cron (or other way) the catalog (categories and products) synchronize from Staging to Production.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to install :

1. Aoe Scheduler [Link](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) . 
   It is a great extension for checking the crons if they are working or not and other features related to crons .
2. Xtento Magento Product Feed Export Module [Link](https://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/magento-product-feed-export-module.html)

Comment: But the module: Xtento Magento Product Feed Export it does not allow me to create a SYNC between two different DBs (staging and production)